# The optimal settings of Winrtgen GUI

Tags: hash, password-cracking, rainbow-table

I'm working with Winrtgen GUI on windows, but I can't fix the right settings to create a rainbow table for a:

password length=1-7 
Charset=alpha numeric all space

What are the ideal values to put in the box "chain len", "chain count" and "N of tables" to generate one or many tables quickly as possible and who does not occupy much memory and guarantees a high percentage of success probability (97 to 100 %)?